# Imaginary Hotelling-Williams t values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation

I'm using the Hotelling-Williams test ([recommended by Steiger](http://ww.w.statpower.net/Steiger%20Biblio/Steiger80.pdf), T2) to compare two dependent Pearson correlation coefficients.

To get a feeling of this method, I plotted the rejection areas for different values of jh and jk. I set kh to be (jk+jh)/2 and n to 270. gray areas represent values for which the null hypothesis could not be rejected, blue is for jk>jh and red is for jh>jk (alpha=0.05, code attached below):

[image]

Two things are surprising here. First, some points bellow the diagonal are blue. Second, the gray area is not symmetric.

So it turns out that for these areas, the formula returns an imaginary t value. Here is the same plot with white for imaginary t values:

[image]

And looking at the formula it seems that when the determinant of the correlation matrix |R| is negative, the expression inside the square root can be negative.

[image]
[image]

Am I missing something? and if not, how should I interpret imaginary t values?

Many thanks,

Tan

MAIN SCRIPT (MATLAB):

```
figure; 
n = 270;
jk_vec = []; jh_vec = []; color_mat = [];
for jk = -1:0.01:1
    for jh = -1:0.01:1
        kh = (jk+jh)/2;
        T = compareCorrelationsT(jk, jh, kh, n);
        p = cdf('t',-abs(T),n-2);
        if p>0.05
            color = [0.5 0.5 0.5];
        else
            if sign(T)==1
                color = [243, 23, 23]*1/255;
            else
                color = [0, 112, 255]*1/255;
            end
        end
        if ~isreal(T)
            color = [1 1 1];
        end
        jk_vec = [jk_vec; jk];
        jh_vec = [jh_vec; jh];
        color_mat = [color_mat; color];
    end
end
scatter(jk_vec,jh_vec,[],color_mat,'filled')
```

HOTELING-WILLIAMS

```
function [ T ] = compareCorrelationsT(jk, jh, kh, n)

R = (1 - (jk^2) - (jh^2) - (kh^2)) + (2*jk*jh*kh);
r = 0.5*(jk+jh);
T = (jk - jh) * sqrt(((n-1)*(1+kh))/(2*((n-1)/(n-3))*R + (r^2)*((1-kh)^3)));

end
```

---

edit: thanks to Dougal's help, here is how the simulation looks like now:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And looking at the formula it seems that when the determinant of the correlation matrix |R| is negative, the expression inside the square root can be negative.

Luckily, correlation matrices are [positive semidefinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-semidefinite_matrix) and so the determinant $\lvert R \rvert$ is always nonnegative.